# Password containg '+' symbol

Tags: android

In my app there is an issue regarding the password.The problem occurs when a  password ends with a + symbol,and while posting the url i got the response as user not found.If any one know the solutions plz help..I think the problem is with encoding of + symbol.so how can i send a password contain + symbol to the server?This is my code for posting url.'

```
    public void doPost (String email,String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, SprinklrHttpException{
        try{
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream ostream=connection.getOutputStream();
                String serverMsg=null;             
                    serverMsg="email="+email+"&password="+password;
                    Log.i("tag","servermsg="+serverMsg);                
                ostream.write(serverMsg.getBytes());
                ostream.close();
                InputStream istream=connection.getInputStream();
                response=convertStreamToString(istream);                
                istream.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
     private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request) throws SprinklrHttpException{
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request, this.httpContext);
            this.responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.i("webResponse","responsecode"+this.responseCode);
            this.message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                this.response = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            }
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        throw new SprinklrHttpException(1000,"");
        }finally {
            if (inputStream != null){
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }                   
                     catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: For clarity, are you using a EditText in Android to get the user input, and than posting on a webpage? If you are posting to a webpage, does it run on php or any other language? For different encodings, I always use [this link](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html)

Comment: Are you applying any transformation on the password? May I guess that you don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE

```
serverMsg="email="+email+"&password="+password;
```

WITH

```
serverMsg="email="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "utf-8")+"&password="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty much unreadable due to bad formatting (Something went wrong while posting it methinks), but you probably have to URL-encode it for the + to get read properly.

In fact, you should always URL-encode all parameters (individually) that you send in the URL of a request if there's any chance of it containing characters outside a-zA-Z0-9. Just apply the URLEncoder.encode() method to your password string, and you should be good to go.

Edit: Formatting got fixed, my assumption was right. You should set "password=" + URlEncode.encode(password), preferably with the right encoding as a second argument.